# "Home" and "End" in IntelliJ terminal on Mac with zsh

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, oh-my-zsh

I would like to bind <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to "End" and "Home" in the IntelliJ terminal on my Mac (this is the very same combination that iTerm uses).

If this is not possible, I could also live with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

I know that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> can be used for jumping to the start and end of a line but for convenience I'd like to use the same combinations as within iTerm.

**Edit**

Interestingly, my keymap shows <kbd>↖</kbd> and <kbd>↘</kbd> as keybord shortcut for `Move Caret to Line End` and `Move Caret to Line Start` - it works in the editor - but it does not work in the terminal:

[image]

**Edit 2**

I found out that the problem occurs only with `zsh` - when I use `bash`, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> work as expected. Any ideas where IntelliJ and `zsh` might conflict here? It works with the very same `zsh` configuration in iTerm.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I haven't changed any key mappings to my knowledge and this is the behaviour I seem to have by default.

I am running:
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3

Comment: In case it is useful, the kaymap I have enabled is: Mac OS X 10.5+

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After searching for a while, I stumbled over this post

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118848

that covers the issue, a fix was proposed here

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4784#issuecomment-180940049

Following this fix, I added

```
bindkey "^[[H" beginning-of-line
bindkey "^[[F" end-of-line
```

to my `.zshrc` and now everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Default OS X bindings have  fn+→ and fn+← to "End" and "Home" respectively.

If that is not the case for you, please update from keymap in settings panel.

Titled arrow shown in keymap binding means fn+→ or fn+← (based on direction of the arrow).

[image]

Comment: see my comment above - I have the very same shortcuts in the keymap, but still doesn't work...

Comment: oh, thats interesting.. how come one process (zsh) intercept commands meant for other process (Intellij). I understand Intellij shortcuts conflicting with OS X shortcuts, but terminal shouldn't ideally affect it.. let me check on my machine too

Comment: see below - found a bug ticket on YouTrack which describes the very same issue. Since I am running on an older version of RubyMine, the problem still occurs for me and I could fix it with the answer given below. Thanks for your help anyway - without your answer, I wouldn't have digged into the problem.

Comment: wow, thats a good find. Glad you were able to fix the problem.